# wsdl2java using Apache Axis2 for WSDL without service

Tags: java, apache, wsdl, apache-axis

I am trying to generate java classes from a WSDL using Apache Axis2. But every time it fails with the following logs:

```
~/Downloads/axis2-1.6.1/bin $ ./wsdl2java.sh -ssi -uri ../HelloWorld.wsdl

 Using AXIS2_HOME: /home/prpandey/Downloads/axis2-1.6.1
 Using JAVA_HOME:  /softwares/jdk1.6.0_31
Retrieving document at '../HelloWorld.wsdl'.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No services found in the WSDL at file:/home/prpandey/Downloads/axis2-1.6.1/bin/../HelloWorld.wsdl with targetnamespace http://www.example.org/HelloWorld/
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:115)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:169)
    ... 2 more
```

Here is the WSDL file: http://pastie.org/3719679

Answer (score 1):

Your WSDL does not define a `wsdl:service` tag. Could this be the error?

Please add a `binding` and a `service` and try again.

Comment: Yes this wsdl doesn't have a wsdl:service and wsdL:binding tag. It is an abstract WSDL. I want to generate java classes for this wsdl only. When I use apache cxf it generates java classes for this same WSDL.

Comment: I dnt think wsdl2java generates java classes for wsdl without service attribute

Comment: If in case I want to generate Java code for an abstract wsdl (server side), it works using apache axis2 with a warning message. I even used option "-ss" while generating with apache CXF but it didn't work.